# Merging two slices of similar data into JSON with Golang

Tags: go

We have a service with two endpoints that hit multiple API's, massage the data and send it back as json. They're serving data on the same objects, but they do distinctly different things. The only common attribute is `uid`.

They're sharing a model, which looks like this:

```
type Item struct {
  Uid     string      `json:"uid"`
  Val1    string      `json:"param1,omitempty"`
  Val2    []NestedVal `json:"param2,omitempty"`
  Val5    int         `json:"param5,omitempty"`
  Val6    string      `json:"param6,omitempty"`
  Val7    string      `json:"param7,omitempty"`
}

type NestedVal struct {
  Val3  int    `json:"val3,omitempty"`
  Val4  string `json:"val4,omitempty"`
}
```

An example response from endpoint `A` would be:

```
[
 {
   "uid": "123",
   "val1": "foobar"
   "val2": [
     {"val3": 666, "val4": "qux"},
     {"val3": 666, "val4": "qux"}
   ]
 },
 {
   "uid": "456",
   "val1": "foobar"
   "val2": [
     {"val3": 666, "val4": "qux"},
     {"val3": 666, "val4": "qux"}
   ]
 }
]
```

An example response from endpoint `B` would be:

```
[
 {
   "uid": "123",
   "val5": 999
   "val6": "bar"
   "val7": "baz"
 },
 {
   "uid": "456",
   "val5": 999
   "val6": "bar"
   "val7": "baz"
 }
]
```

Right now these exist as stand-alone services because they serve slightly different needs, but now we need to offer them up as a combined dataset, something like:

```
[
 {
   "uid": "123",
   "val1": "foobar"
   "val2": [
     {"val3": 666, "val4": "qux"},
     {"val3": 666, "val4": "qux"}
   ],
   "val5": 999
   "val6": "bar"
   "val7": "baz"
 },
 {
   "id": "456",
   "val1": "foobar"
   "val2": [
     {"val3": 666, "val4": "qux"},
     {"val3": 666, "val4": "qux"}
   ],
   "val5": 999
   "val6": "bar"
   "val7": "baz"
 }
]
```

For what it's worth, this is how they're returned (basically the same for both endpoints):

```
func FetchA(uids []string) []Item {
  var collection []Item

  *... fetching, parsing, and appending to collection ...*

  return collection
}

func HandlerA(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
  *... pull uids out of qs ...*
  collection := fetchA(uids)
  responseData, _ := json.Marshal(collection)
  *... write the response ...*
}
```

Bottom line: I have two data sets, both of type `[]Item`. I just want to combine them on their shared `uid` keys. Obviously I'm approaching this as a Ruby dev, thinking about this problem as "I have two arrays of hashes and i want to merge them on a shared key" - I know thats the wrong frame of mind here, but I'm pretty stuck and I know the answer is right under my nose.

I've looked around and none of the answers I've seen have been particularly helpful. I checked out mergeo and go-merge but couldn't find a way around overwriting the merge-ee.

I think my real problem here is a lack of good understanding of Go data structures. This is how I'd combine the two in Ruby:

```
(responseA + responseB).group_by{|h| h[:uid]}.map{|k,v| v.reduce(:merge)}
```

EDIT: Here's a rough simulation on a Go playground https://play.golang.org/p/J0bJMjiM8DR

Comment: Do you always have a 1-to-1 of UID from endpoint A and B? Meaning will you have exactly one UID from each endpoint that maps to the other? Also, you mention concurrent requests, Is there a guarantee that A returns before B or vice versa? A lot of the concurrency depends on the results to these questions, but overall I'd say if you make a map based on the UID and set the results as they come in for each UID in that map you should be good. You would be even better off sending the concurrent responses into a channel and setting them in the map based on what comes through that channel.

Comment: @Verran I tore out the little bit about concurrent requests before I saw this comment - felt like it was extraneous. but that's a really good point.

yeah, they're always 1-to-1. theres a lot less overhead on B and it tends to finish up faster than A, so I'll have to account for that. this is another situation where bringing a Ruby mentality to a language like this is rough.

I'm using channels to manage those concurrent requests. My initial solution to this problem was to make the requests to B inline inside A's fetch function, immediately after the value comes back from the channel

Comment: In that case, channels are probably the way to go, but just make sure to take into account that the index in the map may not exist at any point. Be sure to use the `if _, ok := map[uid]; !ok { map[uid] = Item{}}` check to make sure the Item exists in the map, and then populate the Item afterwards. Otherwise you'll get a index not found error if the Item for that uid hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with "I have two arrays of hashes and i want to merge them on a shared key"

However, in Go you are going to be responsible for doing the merging yourself as their is no notion of a group_by type function / method.

```
func merge(As, Bs []Item) []Item {
    if len(As) == 0 {
        return Bs
    }
    bMap := make(map[string]Item)
    for _, b := range Bs {
        bMap[b.Uid] = b
    }
    merged := make([]Item, len(As))
    for i, a := range As {
        if b, ok := bMap[a.Uid]; ok {
            a.Val5 = b.Val5    // this and the next two lines could be done
            a.Val6 = b.Val6    // using reflection, but if you know the fields
            a.Val7 = b.Val7    // then this would be my preferred way.
        }
        merged[i] = a
    }
    return merged

}
```

Here is a [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lVG6EaOqiEn) of the results

Note: This wouldn't account for an empty slice of As as you would get nothing in the merge.  Since I don't know the specifics of your application I can't say whether that is something that can happen, but if it can you will need to account for it.

For what it's worth, I think this is approximately the approach Verran was suggesting:

https://play.golang.org/p/3EpWlFdB8c6

Basically, let the results be returned on a channel and have them merged as you get both results.

Comment: awesome. this is exactly what i was looking for. makes perfect sense. thank you!

Comment: See note that I just added.

Comment: I added a nil and 0 length check in case it is needed.

Comment: @sberry just fyi `len` on a `nil` slice also returns `0`, making `As == nil` in that `if` redundant.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification. I also made in mistake in my example model - the nested value in an `A` doesn't 'omitempty' like the other attributes, so at a bare minimum an `A` always has has a `uid` and an empty slice in that nested field.

I'll know the fields, but just for future reference - what are the costs of using reflection in a situation like this?

Comment: Ah, indeed @mkopriva